# Element jumps before transform scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scale

I have some nested elements, one of which is an image that scales when you hover over the container. The problem is that the image jumps slightly before it scales. I know it has to do with the extra content inside the container, but I can't figure out why or what to do about it.

I'd also like the scale transformation to reverse smoothly when you stop hovering over the container.

Here is the site: http://totisdev.azurewebsites.net/productos/

Relevant HTML

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slide__content">
        <img />
        <div class="slide__text_hover">
            <h2>Totis</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__text">
            <span>3 Productos</span>
            <h2><span>Totis</span></h2>
            <a href=""><span>ver más </span><img /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Possibly relevant SASS

```
.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 50px;
    .slide__content {
        position: relative;
        max-height: 350px;
        > img {
            max-height: 300px;
            width: auto;
            margin-bottom: -50px;
            margin-left: -72px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
    .slide__text {
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        max-width: 220px;
        h2 {
            box-sizing: content-box;
            font-size: 40px;
            max-width: 280px;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        img {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
    &:hover .slide__content > img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
        transform: scale(1.08);
        -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
    }
    .slide__text_hover {
        display: none;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
        top: -25px;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 25px 25px 25px 150px;
        z-index: -1;
        left: -200px;
        h2 {
            visibility: hidden;
            font-size: 60px;
            max-width: 280px;
            white-space: normal;
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }
    }
    &:hover .slide__text_hover {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    &:hover .slide__text {
        position: relative;
        top: -170px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        transition: transform 0.6s ease;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-left: 200px;
        h2 {
            font-size: 60px;
            max-width: 280px;
        }
        a {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

note: I'm currently transitioning the opacity with javascript, but it shouldn't matter.

Any and all help / feedback appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're moving other elements around while the scale is happening. For a simple proof-of-concept try adding `display:none` to `.slide__text_hover` and `.slide__text` - you'll see that the elements scale up without jumping.

It's up to you how to handle this and how you position these elements because I'm assuming that `display:none` isn't a real solution  You could move the elements around, preallocate the space for these elements, add more code so that the other elements slide over smoothly (transform:translateX) as a few suggestions. This is starting to get into the 'too broad' stackoverflow no-man's-land, though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I don't really understand why the other elements are pulling the image. Could you elaborate on how you would move the elements around or use translateX (I tried and wasn't able to make that work). I don't think pre-allocating space is an option because I don't want to change the appearance of anything before a hover. Also, the elements don't have a fixed width.